# Return Months & days from TimeSpan asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, timespan

I want to return in Seconds, Minuites, Hours, Days, Months et Years from `Datetime` created.

I wrote this snippet of code

```
public static string ReturnCreatedSince(DateTime createdOn)
    {
        //Get current datetime
        var today = DateTime.Now;

        // Get days in current month
        var daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(today.Year, today.Month);

        double seconds = 60;
        double minutes = seconds * 60;
        double hours = minutes * 60;
        double days = hours * 24;
        //double weeks = days * 7;
        double months = days * daysInMonth;
        double years = months * 12;

        //Convert created datetime to seconds
        var datetimeInSeconds = (today - createdOn).TotalSeconds;

        var createdSince = string.Empty;

        if (datetimeInSeconds <= seconds) //seconds between 1 to 60
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(datetimeInSeconds).Seconds.ToString() + " sec";
        }
        else if (datetimeInSeconds <= minutes)// Minuites between 1 to 60
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(datetimeInSeconds).Minutes.ToString() + " mins";
        }
        else if (datetimeInSeconds <= hours)// Hours between 1 to 24
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(datetimeInSeconds).Hours.ToString() + " hrs";                
        }
        else if (datetimeInSeconds <= days)// Days between 1 to 24
        {
            return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(datetimeInSeconds).Days.ToString() + " jrs";
        }           
        else if (datetimeInSeconds <= months)// Months between 1 to 24
        {
           return (datetimeInSeconds / months).ToString() + " m";
        }
        else if (datetimeInSeconds <= years)// Years between 1 to 12 
        {
            return (datetimeInSeconds / years).ToString() + " yrs";
        }
        else
        {
            return createdOn.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
```

I tested the code with the following values

**Edited**

For a given **datetime**

if the number of second is less than 60 then it should return the value in second.
if the number of second is less greater 60 and less than (60 * 60) secs then it should return the value in mins , the same apply for hours, days months and years

Now i have this date `"createdOn": "2017-10-16T14:41:16.557"` and return 41 days instead of 1 month expected.

how can i fix it

Comment: Why isn't it correct ? Did you try to do the calculation by hand ? What result do you expect ?

Comment: this doesn't make any sense to me : `double seconds = 60; double minutes = seconds * 60;` : so the variable `minutes` contains 3600. Is that what you want ? Then I guess it's not a number of minutes (which the variable name would imply for someone like me reading your code) . Same remark for the next variables.

Comment: What is wrong? You want 38 days instead of 1 month? Then your `if`-conditions are wrong.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i want in month when is greater than the numbers of days in the month

Comment: @Pac0 yes i did calculation and the code is clear when is less than 24 hours it should return it in our , same for the days 7 days and also for the month too.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : all months are not the same length. Months difference should not be calculated from the number of seconds.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so how ??

Comment: @Djama: You haven't explained what is wrong. Your code works(could be improved though)

Comment: @Pac0: That's up to OP, if he wants to treat the current month's number of days as a default value then it's perfectly fine. Since every month has a different number of days there is no perfect answer on this anyway. Same with years. You could say one year is 365 or 366 days.

Comment: @TimSchmelter sorry, I intended to direct my comment to OP, not to you. And you are right.

Comment: @TimSchmelter i edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to use embedded methods :

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1970, 01, 01);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
TimeSpan diff = (endDate - startDate);

Console.WriteLine("Number of seconds:" + diff.TotalSeconds);
Console.WriteLine("Number of minutes:" + diff.TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("Number of hours:" + diff.TotalHours );
Console.WriteLine("Number of days:" + diff.TotalDays);

//months 
int nbMonths = ((endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) + endDate.Month - startDate.Month;
Console.WriteLine("Number of months:" + nbMonths);
//years 
int nbYears = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;
Console.WriteLine("Number of years:" + nbYears);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: @daniele let try and see but you didnt add the If part based on that i will be able to say it falls between secs or mins or hours etc ...

Comment: yes i just added the DateTime / Timespan method to get rid of calculation errors, you can apply the same if / else logic after

Answer (score 3):

@Tarik solution for months will get you the total number of months between the startDate and endDate.

To get the last remaining months, include this while loop statement.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2003, 1, 1);
DateTime endDate = new DateTime(2007, 12, 1);
int nbYears = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;
int nbMonths = ((endDate.Year - startDate.Year) * 12) + endDate.Month - startDate.Month;
while (nbMonths > 12)
{
    nbMonths = nbMonths % 12;
}
Console.WriteLine($"{nbYears} year(s) and {nbMonths} month(s)");
```

Without the while loop, it prints: 4 year(s) and 59 month(s)
With the while loop, it prints: 4 year(s) and 11 month(s)